# Internet Explorer 8/9 javascript disable, need to enable back

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This is not a programming issue, just want to ask any one having Internet Explorer Javascript disabled issue. I try go to Internet Option enable everything, including javascript restart it. But all the javascript still disabled.

I go to jQuery API website, test the javascript, at the Demo part nothing show. Even I write a alert("hello"); in a html file, nothing come out.

I am not sure what happen to my Internet Explorer. Initially I am using IE8, I try to update to IE9Beta, IE9RC, the problem start from IE8->IE9RC still haven't resolved. I am not sure what application crash with the IE. 
Please advice! It is Urgent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!
I uninstall it revert to IE8 the problem still the same, TODAY IE9 launch, after I install restart, my Internet Explorer back to normal!
Thanks kyj112!

I think it is because I install beta, RC either one of the version affected the IE. IE9 ROCK!

Answer (score 1):

Go to tools -> internet options -> advanced -> reset and it'll go back to default after restart.  Also restore advanced settings.

If that fails uninstall IE9 or revert back to IE8 and do the above again and see if it helps.

**Update**

Steps to unlock ActiveX Internet Explorer 8

```
1.  Start Internet Explorer 8. 
2.  Press "Tools", after that "Internet Options". 
3.  Now Press on the "Security" tab. 
4.  After that Press on the key "Custom Level." 
5.  Go down to "Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins" The default for this
value is "Enable." If you locate
that ActiveX is allowing untrusted
sites, Press the Reset key to reset
all advanced settings back to their
default values, including ActiveX,
as well as after that restart your
browser.
```

Comment: Not working as well, i try go to safe mode also having the same problem. Do you think possible any application make this problem occur?

Comment: i am going to guess its the IE9 installation

Comment: try to uninstall it and see will it get back to normal

Comment: @Shiro uninstall anything IE related. Then try reinstall.

Comment: I switch back to IE8, when I click on About Internet Explorer, all the detail there is empty, and the OK button is not clickable. the javascript still not working.

Comment: did you remove IE8 and reinstall?  also, reset to default.

Comment: yup, i did uninstall ie8 (at program and feature uncheck internet explorer 8), restart, then check back again. the problem still the same. Totally no idea how to fix, i think i just need to ignore IE, or final solution reinstall my OS.

Comment: @Shiro go into the advance settings tab and reset that too.  are you able to use activex?  there might be a registry fault as well.  that's all i can think of atm.

Comment: I use my IE8 go to http://www.pcpitstop.com/testax.asp , it shows "ActiveX is not supported" , I had reset everything at IE. I got a strong feeling I installed/updated something affected it, but I could not recall what I had installed/updated...

Comment: @Shiro try the update

Comment: Hi, I do try the update, but still the same, I think it is something wrong with registry or serious conflict with IE. Anyway THANKS for you helping. I think I better go to reformat my OS, solve this issue more faster.

Comment: @Shiro sorry, i just got your message, i don't usually use superuser. Last straw is this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/help/ie-9/how-do-i-install-or-uninstall-internet-explorer-9